# how i can crop image while selecting image from gallery?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, crop

im referring this tutorial--> http://www.androidcoding.in/2018/02/17/android-upload-image-using-retrofit-library-part2/

this tutorial only does selecting an image from gallery **not cropping it**

**actually my idea is use to select an image from gallery with crop feature and upload that image using retrofit post which you will find in my code** -->this is implemented except crop feature

only left is cropping..i need help

Following is my code so far -->

```
class EditProfile:AppCompatActivity (){
private val IMAGE = 100
var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
var profile:ImageView?=null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.editprofile)
    var mActionBarToolbar = findViewById<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbartable);
    setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
    // add back arrow to toolbar
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp);
        getSupportActionBar()?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        //supportActionBar?.setTitle("Tables")
        //    getSupportActionBar()?.setTitle((Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + getString(R.string.Myaccount) + "</font>")));

    }
    val myCalendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    val edittext1 = findViewById(R.id.dob) as EditText
    val date =
        OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy" //In which you need put here
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            edittext1.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()))      }

    edittext1.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatePickerDialog(
                this@EditProfile, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            ).show()
        }
    })
   val edit= edittext1.text
     profile = findViewById<View>(R.id.profilepic) as ImageView


    val token :String =SharedPrefManager.getInstance(applicationContext).user.access_token.toString()
    RetrofitClient.instance.fetchUser(token)
        .enqueue(object : Callback<My_account_base_response> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<My_account_base_response>, t: Throwable) {

                Log.d("res", "" + t)


            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<My_account_base_response>,
                response: Response<My_account_base_response>
            ) {
                var res = response

                if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                    //  val retro: List<Myaccount_data> = response.body().getData()

                    val retro: Myaccount_data = res.body()!!.data
                    val retro1 : User_data =retro.user_data
                    Glide.with(applicationContext).load(retro1.profile_pic)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                        .into(profile!!)
                    //image.setImageResource(retro1.profile_pic)
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        val jObjError =
                            JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                         jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        })




    profile?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE)
    })
    editsubmit.setOnClickListener {

        val first_name = firstname.text.toString().trim()
        val last_name = lastname.text.toString().trim()

        val email = emailregister.text.toString().trim()
        val phone = phoneno.text.toString().trim()

        val profile ="data:image/png;base64,"+convertToString()!!
        val token: String =
            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(
                applicationContext
            ).user.access_token.toString()
        val first_name1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), first_name)
        val last_name1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), last_name)
        val email1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email)
        val dob1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), edittext1.text.toString())
        val phone_no1 =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), phone)
        val profile_pic = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
            profile
        )


        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", profile)
        val map: MutableMap<String, RequestBody> = HashMap()

        map.put("first_name", first_name1);
        map.put("last_name", last_name1);
        map.put("email", email1);
        map.put("dob", dob1);
        map.put("phone_no", phone_no1);
        map.put("profile_pic", profile_pic);
        val requestFile: RequestBody =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), profile)

        val body: MultipartBody.Part =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", "image.jpg", requestFile)
        RetrofitClient.instance.useredit(token,map)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.d("res", "" + t)
                }
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                    response: Response<LoginResponse>
                ) {
                    var res = response
                    Log.d("response check ", "" + response.body()?.status.toString())
                    if (res.body()?.status==200) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            res.body()?.message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                        Log.d("kjsfgxhufb",response.body()?.status.toString())
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try {
                            val jObjError =
                                JSONObject(response.errorBody()!!.string())
                            Toast.makeText(
                                applicationContext,
                                jObjError.getString("message")+jObjError.getString("user_msg"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                            ).show()
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            Log.e("errorrr",e.message)
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
    }
}
private fun convertToString(): String? {
      val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    bitmap?.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)

    val imgByte: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP )
}

override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        val path: Uri? = data.data
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, path)
            profile?.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)

            true
        }
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
}
```

really need help thanks in advance

Comment: use any of these libraries from mentioned here and then save it pass it to the api after cropping.

Comment: https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-image-cropper-libraries-3bc4a4f8f2df

Comment: all it needs is an file uri which library will give you after editing it's easy to integrate as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy use
It has file picker in it so you dont have to implement that too.

```
// start picker to get image for cropping and then use the image in cropping activity
CropImage.activity()
  .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
  .start(this);
```

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper